# PDFsharp Not Reading in Correct Page Size

Tags: vb.net, pdf, pdfsharp

I'm trying to develop an application to watermark PDF's. I'm having an issue with saving the PDF document in the correct format.

I've noticed that some documents when pulled in will read the page size as one thing but when I go to save the document part of it will be cut off. For example I have a document saved in landscape at 792x612 pts which correlates to a letter size. However when saved in letter it cuts part of the page off. I noticed that if I save the document in A1 that the entire document will then be present. Here is my code:

```
          Dim gfx As XGraphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Append)
          gfx.RotateTransform(-90)
          Dim font As XFont = New XFont("Times New Romans", 6, XFontStyle.Bold)
          Dim tf As XTextFormatter = New XTextFormatter(gfx)
          Dim rect As XRect = New XRect(-550, 500, 250, 150)
          gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Transparent, rect)
          tf.DrawString(Text, font, XBrushes.Red, rect)
          page.Size = PdfSharp.PageSize.A1
          page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Landscape
          Doc.save(strFileSaveLocation)
```

Is there any reason why this could be happening? I am reading the page.height and page.width and confirming these to be correct before continuing.

Comment: Please don't edit a solution into the *question* but instead make it an *answer* in its own right and accept it as soon as you are allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known bug in PDFsharp when it comes to handling pages in landscape format. This bug is present up to PDFsharp 1.50 beta 3b, but should be fixed with the next release.

See discussion in the PDFsharp forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9591#p9591

Suggested fix in PdfPage.cs:

```
internal PdfPage(PdfDictionary dict)
    : base(dict)
{
    // Set Orientation depending on /Rotate.
    //int rotate = Elements.GetInteger(InheritablePageKeys.Rotate);
    //if (Math.Abs((rotate / 90)) % 2 == 1)
    //    _orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
}
```

If you do not want to modify PDFsharp, maybe try the workaround from the first post:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9587#p9587

Comment: Thanks. Appears to have fixed the saving issue, to some extent. Curious if you know but is there a bug with PDFpage.size and PDFpage.width? I thought that once the page orientation was fixed I'd be able to read the page size, but some documents are showing up as landscape with clearly portrait dimensions and the ability for me to save them is being hindered on knowing if it is portrait or landscape. Prehaps you know of another way to know the orientation the text is in?

Comment: @user2823955  `Size` and `Orientation` of a page work when creating a new page, but they do not work when opening an existing page. `Size` and `Orientation` determine the size of a page, but only `Width` and `Height` persist in the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

For others running into the same issue as me, the answer is to simply set the orientation to portrait. This for some reason will trigger the document to save correctly. The answer by PDFsharp Novice will allow you to fix your code to some extent, but if you're like me and need to know the orientation in order to process the page the solution is setting the orientation back to portrait. You may need to reset page width and height also.

Code:

```
page.Orientation = PdfSharp.PageOrientation.Portrait
page.Width = dblPageWidth
page.Height = dblPageHeight
```